# Finding Jacobian of implicit function.

Tags: calculus, jacobian

If $$u^3=xyz, \frac 1v=\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac 1z, w^2= x^2+y^2+z^2$$, then prove that

$$\frac{\partial(u,v,w)}{\partial(x,y,z)}=\frac{v(y-z)(z-x)(x-y)(x+y+z)}{3u^2w(yz+zx+xy)}$$

Comment: I suggest you try to solve it first by the content of the source this question was stated, then explain it briefly here that what is your problem in solving it. We are not solution manuals.

Comment: I tried by letting $$f_1=u^3-xyz, f_2=frac1v-...... $$ while finding the value of first determinant i.e. in terms of x,y,z the (x-y)(y-z)(z-x) comes out common but the remaining items in the determinant doesn't yield $$\frac{x+y+z}{xy+yz+zx}$$

Comment: Include it in your answer

Comment: Sure I will do it. thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friends! Finally, I caught the point where I was missing. It was $$v^2$$ which was to be partially replaced with $$\frac{xyz}{xy+yz+zx}$$ in the expression which was preventing to reach at the desired result.
Thanks for your humble suggestions.